# Result of type long from a SqlProxyRow result in string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm failing to read the data from a result into the correct type, for example:

```
result = engine.execute("SELECT id FROM table WHERE SetId = 5).fetchall()
```

Column **id** is of type Long in the MySQL DB

```
print result
[(1L,), (2L,), (3L,), (4L,), (5L,), (6L,)]


for row in result:
   print row

(1L,) etc..

print type(row)
 <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.RowProxy'>
```

What is the best way reading those values as the correct type Long? I really don't get how to correctly read out the values from the RowProxy class in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy [`RowProxy` instances](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy) are not strings, but objects with a string representation when printed.

They act like lists and mappings; if all you need are the long values, just loop over the row:

```
for row in result:
    for value in row:
        print value
```

or address each column in the row by it's index:

```
for row in result:
    print row[0]
```

Your query asks for the column `id`, so that is now a key on the row:

```
for row in result:
    print row['id']
```

Comment: Hey and thanks! You should write the documentation for SQLAlchemy! :)

Comment: For the case where each "row" is just a single value, you can iterate and unpack at once just like with multiple values, it's just a little less obvious because the only distinction is a trailing comma, e.g.: `for value, in result:` (it's just like in the multivalue case, `for x, y in z:`, but you need the trailing comma to impose iterable unpacking context).